# How to prevent redirects that are triggered from an imported JS library

Tags: javascript

I am working with a payment gateway that redirects after success.
I want to prevent this from happening.

The payment gateway displays its content in a `div` inside my page.

**Edit**

Redefining the imported function is not an option, as the code is highly obfuscated.

Comment: You'll need to redefine the imported function that does the redirect.

Comment: @Barmar Isn't there any other way? the code is highly obfuscated!

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Angular, you can use HttpInterceptor to identify the URL and cancel the Request...

Comment: The request is not sent from angular.